# How to make existing github repo bare repo

Tags: git, github

I have private github repo. By mistake I have pushed wrong source code. Can I make this repo same as it was created like a bare repo ? 
Just for the experiment I created public github repo https://github.com/shabbirlimdiwala/shabbir_test_repo.git

I followed below steps to make this repo a bare repo,

```
git clone https://github.com/shabbirlimdiwala/shabbir_test_repo.git
cd shabbir_test_repo
mv .git .. 
rm -rf * 
mv ../.git . 
mv .git/* . 
rmdir .git 
git config --bool core.bare true
```

How does these steps made repo a bare repo ?

Comment: can you just delete that repo and create it again?

Comment: yeah, just to to the repository settings, delete it, and create it again with the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permission to do so in case of my private repo. So I have to some how make this a bare repo

Comment: All github repositories are bare. I do not think the word "bare" means what you think it means... http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-keep-using-that-word-i-do-not-think-it-means-what-you-think-it-means (I believe you just want to empty the repo, or force-push a replacement commit.)

Comment: Let me elaborate a little, I want to delete an entire source code (all branches, tags, commits etc..) pushed to github repo without deleting the repo itself.

Comment: Edit the question, don't write additional details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The word "bare" doesn't mean what you think it means.  A "bare" repository refers to a Git repository without an associated working directory (that is, it's what you get when you run `git init --bare ...`).

It sounds from your comments as if you just want to remove the existing repository history from your repository.  It would be much simpler to simple delete and re-create the GitHub repository, but if for some reason that's not possible, the follow should do what you want:

- Clone the remote repository:

  ```
  $ git clone git@github.com:yourusername/yourrepo.git
  ```
- Delete all the remote tags:

  ```
  $ cd yourrepo
  $ git ls-remote --tags origin | awk '!/\^\{}/ {printf ":%s\n", $2}' | xargs git push origin
  ```
- Delete all the remote branches (except for the `master` branch):

  ```
  $ git ls-remote --heads origin | awk '{printf ":%s\n", $2}' | xargs git push origin
  ```
- Replace your local master branch with an empty branch.  First, create a new orphan branch:

  ```
  $ git checkout --orphan newmaster
  ```
- Clean out the index:

  ```
  $ git rm -rf .
  ```
- Make a single empty commit:

  ```
  $ git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial commit'
  ```
- Delete the old master branch:

  ```
  $ git branch -D master
  ```
- Rename the `newmaster` branch to `master`:

  ```
  $ git branch -m master
  ```
- Force push to the remote repository:

  ```
  $ git push -f origin master
  ```

Now your Github repository is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new git directory.
Add your github remote and push it with mirror option.

> git remote add https://...
>
> git push origin --mirror

That will delete all from your remote including tags and braches